# how to stop a fortran program abnormally

Tags: fortran, fortran90

When an exception occurs I would like to terminate abnormally my program. Right now, when an exception happens a `write` statement with an explanatory sentence is called, and then a `stop` statement is called.

I am debugging the program with `idb` (intel debugger), when the exception happens I get the `write` statement, but `idb` treats the program as terminated normally. I would like that when the exception happens the program is terminated abnormally and so that I can look to the memory with `backtrace` in the place where the exception happened.

I have tried changing `stop` in `stop 1`, so that a non zero value is returned, but this doesn't work

EDIT:

I have implemented the solution in one of the answer:

```
 interface
    subroutine abort() bind(C, name="abort")
    end subroutine
 end interface

 print *,1
 call abort()
 print *,2
end
```

with this solution I still do not get any backtrace when I am using `ifort 13.0.1`, but this works perfectly with `ifort  14.0.2`.

I have resorted to use `idb` instead of `gdb`, because often the latter cannot read the values of allocatable arrays in `fortran`.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: @francescalus `error stop` also gives `program exited normally`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are non-standard extensions for this. Gfortran uses `backtrace()` to print a backtrace anywhere, for the Intel's equivalent see the wander95's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38905855/721644.

In ifort and gfortran you can call the `abort()` subroutine and you will get backtrace if you used the `-traceback` (Intel) or `-g -fbacktrace` (gfortran) compiler option.

You could also call the C `abort()` directly using the C interoperability. (also non-standard and may not work in all circumstances):

```
  interface
    subroutine abort() bind(C, name="abort")
    end subroutine
  end interface

  print *,1
  call abort()
  print *,2
end
```

Comment: I think I don't understand you properly: I have changed `stop` into `call abort()` but still I get `program exited normally`. I have compiled with `-g -traceback`

Comment: @simona Perhaps you are hitting this problem? https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/487091 I am getting a backtrace with ifort 14.0.1, although, strangely, it is SIGSEGV and not SIGABRT.

Comment: @simona If you cannot use another version try calling the C function as I do above.

Comment: the interface module to c version of abort does not traceback either

Comment: What does it do then? It should raise a signal which gdb should be able to catch.

Comment: `Program exited normally`

Comment: Which OS, compiler and gdb versions do you use? Btw, idb is now deprecated by Intel, gdb should be used.

Comment: You don't need `-g` in ifort for a traceback. The `-traceback` flag works independently (and without performance hit).

Comment: @A.Hennink You get *a* traceback, but is it *a useful* traceback? Are the symbols meaningful including the line numbers?

Comment: Yes. It ["functions independently of the debug option"](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-traceback). I don't know whether this is also true for `gfortran`.

Setting `-g` is trickier, as it also changes the default to `-O0`, and affects other settings.

Comment: GCC requires `-g`. The `-g` does not set any `-O` level in any of those two compilers if you specify your own `-Osomething` directly. And the default is 0 in most compilers anyway (maybe not Intel) so most often one has to specify it directly. This is a non-issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

With Fortran 2008 the `ERROR STOP` statement has been introduced. It's mainly used for Coarray Fortran programs to initiate error termination on all images.

Comment: I asked initially whether the `error stop` helped (comment deleted before answered as I managed to test it myself).  It appears idb doesn't treat error termination in the desired way,

Answer (score 2):

Found this old question by accident. If you want abnormal termination with the intel compiler, you can use the routine [tracebackqq](https://software.intel.com/en-us/fortran-compiler-18.0-developer-guide-and-reference-tracebackqq). The call sequence can be:

```
     call TRACEBACKQQ(string=string,user_exit_code=user_exit_code)
```

To quote the manual:

> Provides traceback information. Uses the Intel® Fortran run-time library traceback facility to generate a stack trace showing the program call stack as it appeared at the time of the call to TRACEBACKQQ( )

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `idb`, I've only used `gdb`, so this might not work. I just put a read statement in at the error point, so that the program stops and waits for input. Then I can CTRL-C it, which causes `gdb` to pause execution, from which I can get a backtrace, move up and down the stack, look at variables, etc.

Comment: the problem is solved. btw you can also put breakpoints with `b <sourcefile>:<numberoftherelevantline>`