# Non-desired backtrace info in fortran-compiled execution

Tags: compilation, fortran, gfortran, backtrace

I'm developing a fortran code (standard 2003) in which I have to control all non-nominal exits.

When executing the code without arguments (it requires a number of args) I received the expected exit code + some non-asked backtrace info, as you may see below:

```
 ./test_1 
 Error    | Wrong number of inputs in test_1
 STOP 128

 Backtrace for this error:
 #0  0x0000003b9b0ac584 in wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
 #1  0x00007ff41d8ff00d in ?? () from /usr//lib64/libgfortran.so.3
 #2  0x00007ff41d90082e in ?? () from /usr//lib64/libgfortran.so.3
 #3  0x00007ff41d90112f in _gfortran_stop_numeric () from usr//lib64/libgfortran.so.3
 #4  0x000000000041f7d4 in _gfortran_stop_numeric_f08 ()
 #5  0x000000000041b680 in MAIN__ ()
 #6  0x000000000041f74d in main ()
```

The weird thing is that I don't have any flag in my compilation with optimization (I think) to invoke the backtracking.

```
gfortran -Wall -Wextra -Wuninitialized -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 -finit-local-zero -I/opt/cots/netcdf_4.2_gfortran/include  -L/usr//lib64 -Wl,-rpath,/usr//lib64 -L/opt/cots/netcdf_4.2_gfortran/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/cots/netcdf_4.2_gfortran/lib  -o test_1 test_1.o  -lnetcdff -lnetcdf -lz -lm
```

I have it though in the debug mode. But I'm using the optimized executable...

Anyone knows how I can get rid of the backtrace info?

I'm assuming it's nothing related to the code since it appears after the stop order.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which compiler version? Most people will appreciate the backtrace, IIRC it was added on purpose to be the default.

Comment: See https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52594 So try `-fno-backtrace`

Comment: Related  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462371/how-to-stop-a-fortran-program-abnormally/30478403#30478403

Comment: I don't need the backtrace because I'm not debugging, I'm forcing the crash and what I need is a formatted exit. It seems that's the default behaviour so I will use then the -fno-backtrace. Thanks! [my compiler is gcc 4.7.2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `-fno-backtrace` for GCC versions where `-fbacktrace` is the default.