# Fortran show where a subroutine was called

Tags: fortran

In the program I am using, there is a `subroutine open(name,reclen,etc)` to open files in a standardized manner.

The program uses a lot of disk IO out of multiple reasons, and files that are written somewhere are often opened multiple times in different subroutines.

Is there the possibility to print out the current path in a subroutine?

something like

```
subroutine open()
  call print_path()
end subroutine
```

which would print something like a stack trace without killing the program:

```
this instance of open() was called at:

program     line routine/program/function
=========================================
calc        157  subrout1.f90
calc        112  parentrout.f90
calc         20  calc.f90
The opened file here has the name ABC.txt
```

So in this instance I know that the file `ABC.txt` was opened in `subrout1` at line 157 which was called in `parentrout` at line 112 in the program `calc` at line 20.

Comment: You appear to be asking (partly) about _stack traces_.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @francescalus yeah something like that, but can I get a stack trace without my program terminating?

Comment: If you are happy relying on compiler extensions you may be able to (depending on compiler).  Something within the limits of Fortran would be much work.  Which compiler(s) interest you?  (I recall other questions/answers specific to gfortran, ifort.)

Comment: It has to work both with ifort and gfortran.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a backtrace at any time by calling subroutine `backtrace()` in gfortran and `tracebackqq()` in Intel Fortran (see also answers to [how to stop a fortran program abnormally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462371/how-to-stop-a-fortran-program-abnormally)). These are compiler specific. I don't know of any standard solution nor a solution that would be at least common to these two compilers.